# Does a walk after a meal help with digestion?

Tags: digestion

I am a bit confused with the notion that "**walking after meals helps you in digestion** ",

Some say that it helps, whereas others oppose it. Can someone come up with a valid explanation for this?

Comment: This seems like a job for Myth Busters :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

apparently walking helps in the movement of food into the stomach and improves digestion. Also helps in decreasing blood sugar after meals, which decreases cardiovascular risk and potential signal diabetes by helping muscles absorb glucose in the blood. Here is [the link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18392240) to a study done comparing the results of walking after food and after a drink. Also a study [was conducted](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19560716) where when people with Type 2 diabetes took a 20 minute walk just 15 minutes after eating, their post-meal blood sugar levels were lower than if they had walked before dinner or not walked at all. Here is [the link](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/early/2013/06/03/dc13-0084.abstract) to another similar study.

Answer (score 4):

Well it depends what you mean by helping digestion.

This [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/11169/edit) in skeptics may shade some light:

> **a walk after my lunch [is] a healthy habit that helps with digestion.**

Walking may be a healthy habit but it does not specifically assist digestion.

> Digestion is a process which takes place in resting conditions. Exercise is characterised by a shift in blood flow away from the gastrointestinal (GI) tract towards the active muscle and the lungs.

From: [Is the gut an athletic organ? Digestion, absorption, and exercise. [Sports Med. 1993] - PubMed - NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8460288)

So it's seems walking help sugar level (but this is independent to having eaten just before) but seems to not be beneficial to the digestion (in particular stomach contractions ― nutrient absorption will only start in general two hours after your meal, once the food leave the stomac)